# thinking_sphinx generated query cuts off my large indexed text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I've got a weird issue with the `thinking_sphinx` gem for Rails.

We've been indexing contents from documents within our application. Whether it is a pdf, word document or xls, we dump its content directly to the DB using several command line tools. This output is saved to a DB field called `:raw_text`.

In another model, called `thought`, we have an index block for thinking_sphinx as such:

```
define_index sphinx_index_name do
  indexes :title
  indexes :text
  ...
  indexes documents(:raw_text), :as => :thought_document_raw_text
  set_property                  :delta => :datetime, :delta_column => :updated_on, :threshold => TS_DELTA_INDEXING_THRESHOLD
  set_property                  :group_concat_max_len => 4294967295
end
```

Worth mentioning, the document's `raw-text` attribute is also indexed on the `document` model itself. Things get weird when comparing the output of the two generated queries, coming from TS.

When looking up the output for the TS generated query for `document_core` I see the whole text of a indexed pdf file. Yay! Exactly what I've hoped for!

If I run the TS generated query on our `thought` model I only get a fraction of the `:raw_text` found in a column named as we've defined in our index `thought_document_raw_text`.

Since the TS index for `thought` relates to another `document` the query contains some elements to tie these entities together.

`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL('documents'.'raw_text', '0') SEPARATOR ' ') AS
'thought_document_raw_text'` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN 'documents' ON documents.thought_id = thoughts.id`

A stripped down version of the entire query looks like this:

`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 'thoughts'.'id' * 11 + 8 AS 'id' ,     'thoughts'.'title' AS 'title',  'thoughts'.'text' AS 'text',    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL('documents'.'filename', '0') SEPARATOR ' ') AS 'thought_document_filenames',   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL('documents'.'raw_text', '0') SEPARATOR ' ') AS 'thought_document_raw_text',    'thoughts'.'id' AS 'sphinx_internal_id',    CAST(IFNULL(CRC32(NULLIF('thoughts'.'type','')), 1577494256) AS UNSIGNED) AS 'class_crc',   0 AS 'sphinx_deleted'   FROM 'thoughts'     LEFT OUTER JOIN 'documents' ON documents.thought_id = thoughts.id       GROUP BY 'thoughts'.'id', 'thoughts'.'type'  ORDER BY NULL;`

When I check the contents of `thought_document_raw_text` It obviously not the whole text, since the bytesize is smaller (21876 byts)

What is the purpose of this distinct within the group concat?

What are my options to avoid the distinct being generated?

Why is my text blob being cut off?

If someone has had the same problem, or some similar problem regarding large amount of text, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

edit; what I forgot to mention. When I remove the DISTINCT from the generated query, the output matches its fellow TS query for `document_core`. The problem has to do with this specific part!

Answer (score 1):

This is a MySQL issue, but you can customise it to some extent within Thinking Sphinx. The docs have [the lowdown](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#mysql_large_fields).

Comment: I included the group_concat_max_len option in my index block, although this didn't seem to solve my issue. The max_allowed_packet surely doesn't exceed the default of 16mb. The distinct just needs to take a hike :)

Comment: What happens if you set group_concat_max_len in your sphinx.yml file?